# Maven dependencies for org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have added all these dependencies but still `org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument` is not imported. I need it for below code. What is the problem?

```
`POIXMLDocument.hasOOXMLHeader(file.getInputStream())`
```

---

if I click on the error, it will import it manually and everything is fine but I guess it is wrong

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
        <version>0.6</version>
    </dependency>



     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.5-beta4</version>
  </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xbean</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xbean_xpath</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans-qname</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code instead the one in your pom

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>3.5-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: No, it does not changed

Answer (score 0):

Please change the version of the artifact

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
  </dependency>
```

and re-execute maven

Comment: Thanks but it is not changed yet

Comment: Did you try to mvn clean install, Check your .m2 repository whether you have the .jar files in repo

Comment: Try deleting the poi folder in .m2 repo and rerun it

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in your POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
  <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

An InputStream in **hasOOXMLHeader()** method  which supports either mark/reset, or is a PushbackInputStream

Comment: Thanks no changes but:(

Comment: Plz add follwing dependencies and Check                  <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
 <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
 <version>3.10-beta2</version>
</dependency>   and                                      <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
 <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
 <version>3.10-beta2</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

The jar file is in the Maven dependencies and I used `ctrl+shift+o` to import it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

ooxml for dealing the .xlsx files and the ooxml refers to the xml, hence we will be needed to refer the below three dependedncies in the pom.xml for the

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
       <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
       <version>3.9</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
       <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.01</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
       <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
       <version>3.9</version>
       <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
       <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactI`enter code here`d>
       <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
       </exclusion>     
       </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```